# WiFi Not Working on Android TV Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi, android-tv

The Android TV Emulator cannot access the WiFi connection. Isn't WiFi available in Android TV emulators? How can I test an app that needs Internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't WiFi available in Android TV emulators?

WiFi is not available in any SDK emulator.

> How can I test an app that needs Internet connection?

The emulator emulates an Internet connection. It does not emulate WiFi.

Comment: can I ask what does it mean emulates internet connection ? .my laptop is connected via wifi how can I give the T.v emulator to have internet connection ? my app needs to have internet connection but I failed to test in the t.v emulator. thank you in advance